# Vectorizing 'deparse(substitute(d))' in R?

Tags: r, function

I'm wondering why, when running my below using: `bb(d = c(dnorm, dcauchy) )` I get an error saying: `object 'c(dnorm, dcauchy)' not found`?

**P.S.** But as I show below, the function has no problem with `bb(d = c(dnorm))`.

```
bb <- function(d){

 d <- if(is.character(d)) d else deparse(substitute(d))

  h <- numeric(length(d))
for(i in 1:length(d)){
  h[i] <- get(d[i])(1)  ## is there something about `get` that I'm missing?
    }
  h
}
# Two Examples of Use:
bb(d = dnorm)                # Works OK 
bb(d = c(dnorm, dcauchy) )   # Error: object 'c(dnorm, dcauchy)' not found

# But if you run:
bb(d = c("dnorm", "dcauchy"))# Works OK
```

Comment: When you deparse it you get `"c(dnorm, dcauchy)"`, literally.

Comment: Because `get()` needs the name of a variable. You cannot use it with functions. For example `get("x")` would return the value for `x`, but `get("c(x)")` would not "call" the `c()` function. It works with names, not expressions. For reasons like this it's generally best to avoid `get()`.

Comment: Maybe there's a part of what you're doing that you've omitted, but I don't see why you couldn't just pass the functions themselves (or a list of functions) as arguments and skip all the deparsing/get stuff.

Comment: @joran, so in my edited code, now `bb(d = c("dnorm", "dcauchy"))` runs fine!?

Comment: @MrFlick, so is their any alternative (or a modification) to what `get()` does such that for my current function `bb(d = c(dnorm, dcauchy))` would run fine?

Comment: Right, but you could just pass `list(dnorm,dcauchy)` and you would have a list of the _actual_ functions and not have to do any of the deparse/get stuff to be able to call them in your function.

Comment: @rnorouzian It all depends on what you want the behavior (output) to be when you pass more than one function. Seems like it would just be easier to pass in a list of function.  No need for deparse/get at all in that case. `bb(d = list(dnorm, dcauchy))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this alternative where you pass the functions directly to your function

```
bb <- function(d){
  if (!is.list(d)) d <- list(d)
  sapply(d, function(x) x(1))  
}

bb(d = list(dnorm, dcauchy))
bb(d = dnorm)
```

The `c()` function is meant to combine vectors, it's not a magic "array" function or anything. If you have collections of simple atomic types, you can join them with `c()`, but for more complicated objects like functions, you need to collect those in a list, not a vector.