# R: Vectorize deparse(substitute(x))

Tags: r, parsing, vectorization

I want to vectorize `deparse(substitute(x))`.

```
f <- function(...){
deparse(substitute(...))
}

f(a, b, c)
```

This gives only the first element, `"a"`, but I await `"a", "b", "c"`. By accident, I found this

```
f2 <- function(...){
deparse(substitute(...()))
}
f2(ab, b, c)
```

This gives `"pairlist(ab, b, c)"`. Now I could delete all the stuff I do not need to obtain `"a", "b", "c"`. But this seems not elegant to me. Is there a way to vectorize deparse(substitute(x))?

I know there is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336517/vectorizing-deparsesubstituted-in-r) with a similar issue but the answer does not include `deparse(substitute(x))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match.call` is a good starting point.  I'd encourage you to explore all what you can do with it.  I believe this gets you where you want though:

```
f <- function(...){
    as.character(match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)[[2]])
}
```

and an example of using it...

```
f(hey, you)
[1] "hey" "you"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `match.call`

```
f <- function(...) sapply(as.list(match.call())[-1], as.character)
f(a)
#[1] "a"
f(a, b)
#[1] "a" "b"
f(a, b, c)
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

---

Or using `substitute`

```
f <- function(...) sapply(substitute(...()), deparse)
f(a)
#[1] "a"
f(a, b)
#[1] "a" "b"
f(a, b, c)
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
```